# Is it possible to setup DFS without active directory

Tags: windows-server-2008, dfs-r

Is it possible to create a distributed file system without active directory?  We have 3 servers to replicate files across.  A will be the primary and B & C need to have a copy of the same files.  The biggest problem we face is that C is the other side of the country and so not on the same network.

Open to alternatives to DFS if it's not.

Comment: Related question: https://serverfault.com/questions/803114/windows-server-replicate-folders-without-dfs

Answer (score 3):

You can set up a stand-alone DFS Namespace without an AD domain, but to quote [the documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc773238(v=ws.10).aspx):

> ### Can I use DFS Replication in a workgroup?
>
> No. DFS Replication relies on Active Directory® Domain Services for configuration. It will only work in a domain.

Comment: So yes, but no? :)

Comment: You cannot replicate using DFS-R, no :-)